# file_get_contents doesn't write to a log file

Tags: php

I am trying to write content to a log file using form input data. This doesn't seem to work on a server that's is using php version 5.3.14 but when i put the same code on a server that uses 5.3.27 its working. Does any one have an idea on how to fix this?

Below is my code that i am using for my form action. incoming.log is the file that i am trying to write to and is found in the folder path live/lms on the server. Please not that i am not getting any errors.

```
<?php

$system_path = '/live/lms/';
$fh = fopen($system_path . "incoming.log", "a");
fwrite($fh, "\nReceived:\n" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n" . file_get_contents("php://input"));

fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: *This doesn't seem to work* What does that mean? Do you get any errors? Is it writing something in your log? e.g. `coffee coffee i need coffee` or what?

Comment: @Rizier123 no i am not getting any error and not writing anything to the log file.

Comment: Do the folders have the same permissions on both servers?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`

Comment: It's more likely this is something to do with different servers, than the PHP version. Are you certain you have errors enabled on the server where it's not working? Write permissions for the folders/files involved etc?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but advise:
You should add more error handling ...and structure the script in a way so you *can* add more error handling.
For starters (work in progress):

```
<?php
$system_path = '/live/lms/';
$fhSource = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
if (!$fhSource) {
    trigger_error('fopen input: '. print_r(error_get_last(), true), E_USER_ERROR );
}

$fhTarget = fopen($system_path . "incoming.log", 'a');
if (!$fhTarget) {
    trigger_error('fopen output: '. print_r(error_get_last(), true), E_USER_ERROR );
}

$cb = stream_copy_to_stream($fhSource, $fhTarget);

var_dump($cb);

fclose($fhSource);
fclose($fhTarget);
```

Comment: you are very close. It can not open log file. Question is, how is this possible when i have set my permissions to 777.

Comment: When you replace the rather crude `or die(...)` hm, let's still call it "error handler" by something a little bit more sophisticated that includes `var_dump(error_get_last());` do you get a more useful error report?

Comment: take a look at the error log of php or (for developing purposes only) edit your php.ini and set display_startup_errors to true - it's most certainly a syntax error ...or the error reporting is too low (for trigger_error/E_USER_ERROR)